# Background image not resizing - C#

Tags: c#, image, background, resize

I set `BackgroundImageLayout` to `Stretch`, but the background image is not resizing correctly.

Here's what my form originally looks like:
[image]

And here's what happens when I resize it:
[image]

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

EDIT:
1 - I'm using WinForms;

2 - It's the background image of a Form.

3 - Here a photo of my project's properties:

[image]

Comment: Please provide some relevant details besides the images - what framework is this? WPF? UWP? WinForms? Xamarin? What control is are you using?

Comment: @CoolBots I'm using WinForms

Comment: Is the control a `PictureBox`? If so, Id set it to `Center` instead of `Stretch`, and size the `PictureBox` accordingly. Also, why `BackgroundImageLayout`? Is this a background image on a `Form` control then? You need to include these details in your post. As is, it's basically anybody's guess as to what's going on.

Comment: No, that's the background image of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a simple fix would be to add this to the forms Resize event, like this:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Refresh();
}
```

On a side note, unfortunately, for reasons I don't understand, this should fix it, but in my testing it did not:

```
this.ResizeRedraw = true;
```

It looks like a bug in the MDI forms implementation to me. The background image also would not show up properly in design mode on my system when the form "IsMdiContainer" is set to true.

Answer (score -1):

It should work if the background image is set as shown below.

```
whatever.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
```

Can you put a photo of your property settings?

Comment: You can also use the picture box
If the background image of the form does not work properly